# Странное поведение windows

Tags: windows, драйвер, аудио, windows-7, ноутбук

Я не знаю, как точно охарактеризовать мою проблему в заголовке, но windows ведет себя немного странно.

По порядку:

У меня стоит 2 системы: основная kUbuntu, a вторая windown.Сначала устанавливался windows, а потом я заинтересовался linux'ом. В windows было 2 раздела на жестком диске: C и D.Я от диска D оттяпал несколько десятков гигов, распилил на  части (/, swap, /home) и благополучно поставил linux. Когда в /home стало мало места, я оттяпал от диска D еще десяток. 4 раза я повторял данную процедуру, и все было нормально. На 5-й раз, я оттяпал еще. После чего у меня слетел диск D (windows предлагал форматнуть диск). Информация была частично восстановлена. Но, самое интересное то, что у меня пропал в наушниках звук. Именно в наушниках. Потому что через колонки ноутбука звук идет, а стоит только подключить наушники/колонки в гнездо, так звука нет. Хотя realtek пишет что-то типа "подключен разъем". С гнездом все замечательно, так как на kUbuntu все работает. Переустановка драйвера не помогла. Танцы с бубном и перешаривание гугла так же оказались бесполезными. Помогите, пожалуйста!

[Вот ноутбук](http://spb.notik.ru/goods/11368.htm), драйверы качал с официального сайта

Comment: P.S. Винду я переустанавливать не хочуНа диске D всегда было свободное место при "оттяпывании"Перед "отрезанием" всегда проводил дефрагментацию.Звук в наушниках появлялся 2 раза (не по порядку) после такой ерунды.Махинации с жестким проводились в kUbuntu в программе gPartedПовторюсь:4 раза удачно отрезал от диска D гигабайты, на 5й все полетело

Comment: "Винду я переустанавливать не хочу"windows я храню только для некоторых "виндозных" программ: fl-studio и PhotoShop. Если для второго наушники не нужны, то для первого без них никак

Comment: На самом деле, странно windows себя ведет. Особенно если учесть то, что диск С не был тронут вообще

Comment: Я постоянно убеждаюсь в том, что windows -- не самый лучший выбор. К сожалению, на linux пишется мало программ, необходимых многим. Поэтому, порой просто вынуждаешься запускаться под windows.Про wine я знаю. Но, учитывая то, откуда у меня руки, я покалечил 3 раза систему. (не так уж и просто поставить asio4all под linux да так, чтобы он работал как на windows)

Answer (score 1):

Надо бы диск проверить на бэды через mhdd или victoria.

Answer (score 1):

Звук, кроме как в Windows настройках, так же можно настраивать в тулзе драйвера, так называемых Audio Deсk'ах.
Возможно что-то там разведать возможно будет.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте выполнить команду sfc /scannow от имени администратора.

Comment: Сделано. Ничего не изменилось